# Move Exchange 2000 mailboxes from old domain to Exchange 2007 in new domain

Tags: exchange

I need to move 100's of Exchange 2000 mailboxes from an old domain to a new domain and onto a new Exchange 2007 server.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is your new domain in a new forest, or in a completely separate forest?

Comment: Dit you try to establish a trust relationship between your domains, migrate the accounts and use the move mailbox cmdlets? Also you might see this article ->http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997145(EXCHG.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move mailboxes from a server running Exchange 2000 Server directly to Exchange Server 2007. You're going to have to migrate the mailboxes to an Exchange Server 2003 machine first. Once you've done that, Microsoft's [How to Move a Mailbox Within a Single Forest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997961(EXCHG.80).aspx) article will tell you what you need to do.